# -Could not get consecutive bytes in internal RAM for area DSEG

Tags: c, printf, 8051

```
 char buffer[33];
 unsigned int rush = 9876;
 sprintf(buffer,"%u",rush);
```

Implementing this code in sdcc. However with the use of sprintf function, I'm getting ASlink error: Could not get 127  consecutive bytes in internal RAM for area DSEG.

Can anyone please help rectify this.

I need to convert the integer value to string to display it on lcd.

Comment: Probably you ran out of data memory.

Comment: You should not need a 33 byte array for a toaster oven.

Comment: lol, just noticed the '8051' tag.  I would never have guessed... :)

Comment: 'I need to convert the integer value to string to display it on lcd. - do it one char at a time as you process the int.  You cannot faff about with 'normal' code on a controller with less RAM than Trump has good ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sprintf() - your controller has enough RAM to run a toaster oven and that's it.

If you need to output an int/longint on an LCD, use printf/putchar, or some dedicated loop, (NOT RECURSION - you don't have the stack for it), that generates the string representation of the integer char-by-char and send it to the display char-by-char, so avoiding the need for the RAM buffer that you cannot afford.

Comment: There are many 8051 variants still on the market, some with more than enough (X)RAM.